# Kivy AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, camera, attributes, kivy

I am trying to add a screen to my app to take photos but I keep getting this error when clicking the capture button : `AttributeError: 'AddPhotoScreen' object has no attribute 'capture'`

Here is my kivy and main.py file :

````
<AddPhotoScreen>:
    name: "addphoto"
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (1280, 800)
            play: True

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2
            spacing: 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.1}
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "camera"
                user_font_size: "64sp"
                text_color: 0,0,0,0.9
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
                on_press: root.capture()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "keyboard-backspace"
                user_font_size: "64sp"
                text_color: 0,0,0,0.9
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
                on_release:app.root.current = "nouvelele"```



Main.py file

class AddPhotoScreen(Screen):
    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()
        
class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):

        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print ("Photo Added")
````

I am guessing the problem is because of `on_press: root.capture()`but I don't understand since the `class AddPhotoScreen`is returning `CameraClick`.
This code is almost entirely copy/pasted from the kivy exemple gallery and therefore it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clearly stated by the error message. Your `AddPhotoScreen` has no method named `capture`. The return from some other method has no effect on that fact. You need to implement the `capture()` method in `AddPhotoScreen`.